# Recursively group strings based on length

Tags: ruby, string, recursion, concatenation

I have

```
strings = ["aaa", "bb", "ccc", "ddd", "e", "ff", "rrrrrrrr", "tttttttt", "a"]
```

I want to group the strings in the array so that each element is no longer then 5 and not shorter then 9. The strings have to maintain their order in the array.

EDIT: Sorry for confusion, yes - at least 5 and at most 9.

the outcome I am looking for is:

```
 result  = ["aaabbbccc", "dddeff", "rrrrrrrr", "tttttttta"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, could you show the output you're looking for?

Comment: "no longer than 5 and not shorter than 9" describes an empty set. Do you mean "at least 5 and at most 9"?

Comment: Seconding the confusion. Are you trying to design some kind of sorting algorithm? There's `Array#sort_by` if all you need is a simple [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: Very baffling i must say. you have triple b in the expected outcome where as only a double b in input. typo?

Comment: if the input was ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "f", "rrrrrrrr", "tttttttt", "a"], it would result in what? do you split the 8"r"s? to make the dddf string at least 5?

Comment: No I expect not to split any strings, just take the smaller ones as they are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question was specified in a rather confusing way, this is the best I could come up with.

```
strings.inject(['']) { |a, s| a.last.size + s.size <= 9 ? a.last << s : a << s ; a }
#=> ["aaabbccc", "dddeff", "rrrrrrrr", "tttttttta"]
```